# Ubuntu Server Open Port, nothing works

Tags: networking

I'm trying to open ports and I'm totally frustrated.

I work on: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I tried the below commands:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow 500
sudo ufw allow 500/udp
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
sudo ufw reload
sudo ufw restart
```

But when I checked if port is enable whith `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN`

I got the following output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1247/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1247/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1245/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1247/named
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1465/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      1247/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1245/sshd
```

And I can't reach port 500, I am totally frustrated.

And the `sudo ufw status verbose` output (a litle messy);

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
23                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8080/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9010:9030/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9010:9030/udp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere
500:4500/tcp               ALLOW IN    Anywhere
500:4500/udp               ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8                          ALLOW IN    Anywhere
222                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2222                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9191/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9191/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
8111                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    1.2.3.4
151.80.41.166 8111/tcp     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    1.2.3.4
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
500/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
4500/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
23 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8080/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9010:9030/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9010:9030/udp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
500:4500/tcp (v6)          ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
500:4500/udp (v6)          ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8 (v6)                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
222 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2222 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9191/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9191/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
8111 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
500/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
4500/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Did you reload (`sudo ufw reload`), or restart (`sudo systemctl restart ufw`) ufw?

Comment: Yep, i add to original post. In order to oferr more information

Comment: Then add `sudo ufw status verbose` to post also!

Comment: There's nothing like `sudo ufw restart`! Please check that

Comment: I don't see anything in your netstat output that would indicate that you have any service listening on port 500. What exactly are you expecting to see?

Comment: My Rancher-agent listening

Comment: See if its open with `sudo nmap [ip|localhost] | grep 500`

Comment: whit `sudo nmap localhost | grep 500` nothing happends

Comment: Are you sure that the service is running and listening on port 500? Did you see anything to that extent or an error message in its log?

Comment: Your service may be running, but your evidence seems to show that it's NOT listening on port 500. Solve that first.